# Necesito saber el valor del medio en una tupla (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

Hola buenas estoy haciendo unos ejercicios de lógica con haskell y tengo que sacar el valor del medio de una tupla de 3 utilizando las funciones "maximo" y "mínimo" desarrolladas a continuación.

```
maximo :: (Int,Int)->Int
maximo (x,y) = if x > y then x else y

minimo :: (Int,Int)->Int
minimo (x,y) = if x < y then x else y

med :: (Int,Int,Int)->Int
med (x,y,z) = // funcion med

main = do
print(med(4,3,5))
```

Estuve probando varias combinaciones pero siempre hay al menos un caso en el que falla.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

med :: (Int,Int,Int)->Int

med (x,y,z) = maximo(minimo(maximo(x,y), z), minimo(maximo(x,z), y))

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
med :: (Int,Int,Int)->Int
med (x,y,z) = maximo(minimo(maximo(x,y), z), minimo(maximo(x,z), y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero implementaría las funciones `maximo` y `minimo` de una forma más acorde al estilo *haskell*:

```
maximo :: Int -> Int -> Int
maximo x y | x > y     = x
           | otherwise = y

minimo :: Int -> Int -> Int
minimo x y | x < y     = x
           | otherwise = y
```

Para obtener la función `med` en función de estas dos, podemos usar la estratagema de calcular los mínimos de las combinaciones posibles de parejas y luego obtener el máximo de los tres mínimos, que será el número del medio que buscamos:

```
med :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
med x y z = maximo (maximo (minimo x y) (minimo x z)) (minimo y z)
```

Para que quede más claro, podemos crear una función auxiliar que calcule el máximo de tres números:

```
max3 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
max3 x y z = maximo (maximo x y) z

med :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
med x y z = max3 (minimo x y) (minimo x z) (minimo y z)
```